# how to avoid a return statement in recursion

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, c#-3.0

This program is for printing sum of all the numbers in the array given as input parameter. However this does not happen. Please let me know what is the mistake and provide me the solution with explanation.

```
namespace linkedLists
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            int x = sumOfNum(arr, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static int sumOfNum(int[] arr, int x)
        {
            int[] arr_new = new int[arr.Length - 1];
            if (arr.Length > 1)
            {
                x += arr[arr.Length - 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    arr_new[i] = arr[i];
                }
            }

            if (arr.Length > 1)
            {
                sumOfNum(arr_new, x);
            }

            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your algorithm? The recursion is absolutely unneccessary in this situation. You can replace everything by `int sum = 0; foreach (var x in arr) sum += x; return sum;`

Comment: @Bas: Perhaps they were required to use recursion as an exercise.

Comment: You do not tell us what actually happens! When you test it in your debugger, does the first top-level call do what you expect, i.e. pass an array one shorter containing all but the last element and the last element as subtotal to the next level? And the 9th call ought to receive an array of length 1, skip the recursion and return the total — does that happen?

Comment: There's no need for the recursion.

Comment: You should try testing it on simple cases: an array with 0 elements (works) and 1 element (returns 0, regardless of the array contents), then debugging if necessary to find out what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's title is "how to avoid a return statement in recursion", which is exactly what you should be doing instead of avoiding in a recursion scenario.

But this is not the only problem with your code, because it does nothing like what you described it is supposed to do.

As already mentioned in the comments, this is not something that requires (or for which it is recommended) to use a recursive approach. It can be done, but is inefficient and could lead to a stack overflow if you have a large input array (it needs a new stack frame for each recursive method call in c#).

To solve this recursively, you need to try and state the problem as a recursive problem, before you start trying to code it. In pseudo code, for an input array `x` of size `n`:

```
array_sum(x):
    if (x is empty)
        return 0;
    else
        return x[0] + array_sum(x[1:n-1])
```

An implementation in C# would try to avoid allocating a new array instance (as opposed to what one of the non-functioning parts in the code of your question is doing), and instead keep track of the start index into the input array:

```
public static array_sum(int startIndex, int[] x) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @PJTraill, given the question, I don't think it would be conducive to complicate an explanation by including computational or space complexity arguments. I think "not that efficient" and "avoid allocating a new array instance", should suffice.

Comment: Fair enough ... ‘not that efficient’ just seemed a bit mild in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are required to use recursion as an exercise I will comment no further on that.

The reason your programme does not work appears to be that when the array has only one element, your do not add that element to the subtotal (that you call `x`) before returning it.

While recursion is somewhat expensive, your program uses roughly ½arr.Length² `int`s, which would need a terabyte of memory in the unlikely event that you applied it to an array of length 500,000! So you would be far better not to copy the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the answer without the recursion you just iterate over it while summing the numbers.

If you want to make a recursive solution the `return` is essential. Without it the recursion is just a different way of making a for loop.

```
public static int sumOfElements(int[] arr, int currentIndex, int accumulator)
{
   if( finished-expression ) 
      return accumulator; 
   else
      return sumOfElements(...);
}

public static int sumOfElements(int[] arr)
{
    return sumOfelements(arr, 0, 0);
}
```

Your mistake is that `x` is a different one at each iteration. You don't use the returned value from the recursion so you have the sum of one element as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous comments about recursion, inefficiency, and complexity but as an exercise below is the minimal number changes to get the code to work.

Changes:

1. Added array size guard
2. Moved sum out of if-block
3. Added return statement

Code:

```
namespace linkedLists
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            int x = sumOfNum(arr, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static int sumOfNum(int[] arr, int x)
        {
            if (arr.Length == 0) return x; // Change #1
            int[] arr_new = new int[arr.Length - 1];
            x += arr[arr.Length - 1]; // Change #2
            if (arr.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    arr_new[i] = arr[i];
                }
            }

            if (arr.Length > 1)
            {
                return sumOfNum(arr_new, x); // Change #3
            }

            return x;
        }
    }
}
```